# Putting a background image in a div tag

Tags: html, css, image, background

I'm trying to display an image as the background in a div tag that spans an h1, h2, and horizontal nav bar. My image path is correct-- I tested it as the background for just the h1, just the h2, etc. However, it just won't show up when placed in my div tag. Furthermore, if I try to just use a simple color as the background of my div tag, that doesn't work either.

CSS:

```
#main{
    background-image:url("images/wall.png");
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <h1>Brian Buch</h1>
    <h2>Pianist</h2>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>recordings</li>
        <li>calendar</li>
        <li>bookings</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. http://jsfiddle.net/phLk84pm/ There is probably some other css which is preventing the background-image from showing up.

Comment: try adding a background color to the div, so you can see if the div itself is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You've put your images into an "images" folder, so it's likely you've put your css in a "css" folder.

If so, try this:

```
background-image:url("../images/wall.png");
```

The css is calling the background image from its own relative path... *not the relative path of the page that is using the css.*

That will force the page to look in the /images directory, rather than the /css/images directory.